# How to use a try catch to throw an exception when x = negative

Tags: java

How to use a `try catch` to throw an exception when `x` = negative?

For example all I have is:

```
try {
  if(DaysNum > 0){
     return DaysNum;
  }
}

catch(...){
}
```

Comment: How about `if (x < 0) { throw new RuntimeException("..."); }`?

Comment: `if (DaysNum <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("DaysNum should be positive");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw either create your custom checked exception and Catch it like this.

```
class NegativeException extends Exception {}
```

```
try {
           if(DaysNum > 0){
               return DaysNum;
           }
   throw new NegativeException("number is negative");
} catch (NegativeException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

or you can throw RuntimeException like this

```
try {
           if(DaysNum > 0){
               return DaysNum;
           }
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("number is negative");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Have a [look](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) here to find difference between checked vs unchecked exception

Answer (score 1):

Try,catch is not directly to trigger an exception, but rather when you expect one to be thrown and want to handle it in a specific way.

So if you only want to throw an exception your approach would look something as follows:

```
if(DaysNum > 0){
    return DaysNum;
}
else {
    throw new DaysNegativeException();
}
```

Keep in mind `DaysNegativeException` would also need to be created first.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use a catch block to throw an expcetion. You can throw exception using  `throw` key word.

```
 if(DaysNum > 0){
               return DaysNum;
   }else{
       throw new MyCustomExpception("With some message");
  }
```

Even you can do the something in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a try catch lock to throw an exception.

You can use:

```
if (x<0) throw new RuntimeException("x is negative");
```

Answer (score 0):

The try catch block doesn't throw exceptions. This is done by the

```
throw
```

keyword. To throw an exception you could say

```
throw new Exception();
```

The current method will halt and provide the exception to the calling method until it reaches the end or until it reaches a try catch block with try { } catch (Exception e) { } as signature. In the block of the catch you can then do some logging or alternative code to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use custom exceptions

```
if(DaysNum>0){
   return DaysNum;
}else{
  throw new NegativeDaysException();
}
```

UserDefined exception should extend Exception class as to make it checked Exception where calling method will handle that exception

```
public class NegativeDaysException() extends Exception{}
```